# IT 140 project 2

Tags: python

I have been working on my video game for my class project and we are using dictionaries in order to create a videogame story board. My current code allows me to move rooms just fine but the only item it is adding is the word 'item' into the inventory. I am still in the preliminary steps and I am more curious than stuck on why the coding is acting this way.

```
def user_instructions():
    print('--------------')
    print('You are alone at the hospital late at night when a sick dog shows up at the doorstep!')
    print('Your goal is to collect all 6 items and bring them to the Treatment Area to save the dog!')
    print('Their life is in your hands!')
    print('\nMove through the rooms using the commands: "west", "south", "north", or "east"')
    print('Each room contains an item to pick up, use command: "(item name)"')
    print('\nGood Luck!')


#define command available for each room
rooms = {
    'Lobby': {'east': 'Pharmacy', 'south': 'Bathroom', 'west': 'Exam Room 1', 'north': 'Kennel', 'item': 'no items'},
    'Exam Room 1': {'east': 'Lobby', 'item': 'stethoscope'},
    'Kennel': {'east': 'Exam Room 2', 'south': 'Lobby', 'item': 'blanket'},
    'Exam Room 2': {'west': 'Kennel', 'item': 'thermometer'},
    'Pharmacy': {'west': 'Lobby', 'north': 'Treatment Area', 'item': 'medicine'},
    'Treatment Area': {'south': 'Pharmacy', 'item': 'dog'},
    'Bathroom': {'north': 'Lobby', 'east': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'cleaning supplies'},
    'Kitchen': {'west': 'Bathroom', 'item': 'Food'}
}

def user_status(): #indicate room and inventory contents
    print('\n-------------------------')
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room))
    print('In this room you see {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
    print('Inventory:', inventory_items)
    print('-------------------------------')

def invalid_move():
    print('Command not accepted, please try again')

def invalid_item():
    print('Item is not found in this room')
    user_status()



user_instructions()

inventory_items = [] #list begins empty
current_room = 'Lobby' #start in lobby
command = ''


while current_room != 'Treatment Area': #Treatment area is the end of the game, no commands can be entered
    user_status()
    command = input('Enter your next move.\n').lower()
    if command in rooms[current_room]:
        if command in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            inventory_items.append(command)
        else:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
    else:
        print('Invalid command')

if len(inventory_items) != 6:
    print('You Lose')
    
else:
    print('you win')
```

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should be about the _specific technical problem_ that prevents you from completing your project successfully, not about the project itself. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122). Code that's unrelated to the problem (like printing instructions) should be refactored out before asking a question, as per [mre] guidelines.

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run the code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: Your [mcve] should also contain the minimal inputs necessary to reproduce the error or problem. I would assume it's because you are appending the `command` to your list, not the value tied to the `item` key, but we can't know that without knowing what you are entering

Comment: Look at your code.  You are adding `command` to the `inventory_items`, and the command is always going to be `item`.

Answer (score 0):

`if command in rooms[current_room]:` will only allow you to enter one of the keys of the dictionary for the current room. Since the item names are in the value of the `item` key, not the key itself, you can't enter an item name there.

You could split this into two commands -- first the user enters something like `take`, then you prompt for the name of the item and check that it's in the `item` element.

```
while current_room != 'Treatment Area': #Treatment area is the end of the game, no commands can be entered
    user_status()
    command = input('Enter your next move.\n').lower()
    if command == 'take':
        item = input('What do you want to take? ').lower()
        if item in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            inventor_items.append(item)
        else:
            print(f"There's no {item} here.")
    elif command in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
    else:
        print('Invalid command')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to handle this would be to define a function for retrieving an item, as so, and rather than using

```
    def invalid_item():
```

Use

```
    def retrieve_item(location, command, rooms, inventory):
        inventory.append(rooms[location]['Item'])
        del rooms[location]['Item']
```

This well remove the corresponding item after retrieval.

Also for prompting for input, and input validation, you could try this(just capitalize all Key-Value pairs in your dictionary):

```
    command = input("Enter your next move.\n").title().split()
```

The title method of course returns a copy of the string in which the first letters are capitalized, and .split() arranges the input entry as a List[] of strings.
You could handle movement in a manner such as "go east", or whichever direction. And for retrieving an item using "get" item:

```
    try:
         if len(command[0]) == 3 and command[0] == 'Get' and 
         ''.join(command[1:]) in rooms[location]['Item']:
            
            print('You pick up the {}'.format(rooms[location]['Item']))                
            retrieve_item(location, command, rooms, inventory)
    except KeyError:
         print('invalid command')
```

Hope this helps!